# "Схлопнуть" миграции EF?

Tags: entity-framework

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [“Rebasing” EF migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499536/rebasing-ef-migrations/18499575)

У меня есть проект в котором используются миграции EF, их уже накопилось достаточно большое количество.

Я хочу "схлопнуть" старые миграции в одну, по аналогии с тем, как в git делается `rebase` и `squash`? Есть ли какой-то рекомендуемый способ для этого?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499536/rebasing-ef-migrations/18499575

Answer (score 1):

Выполните следующие действия:

- Удалите существующие миграции
- Выполните в Package Manager Console
  команду `Add-Migration SetupDatabaseFromScratch`
- Выполните (там же) команду `Update-Database`

И да -- **не забывайте про резервные копии**!

Также вы должны очистить таблицу `_MigrationHistory` в случае, если вы хотите сохранить данные в базе. Но сначала сделайте бекап перед выполнением этой операции.

Comment: Пробовал сегодня вариант с сохранением данных -- почему-то не получилось, надо будет разобраться. И, имя InitialCreate привычнее и полностью безопасно (префикс дата перед именем).

Comment: что бы не потерять данные, после *схлопывания* миграций, я поступаю следующим образом: в новой миграции комментирую код создания таблиц(все что внутри `Up`), затем возвращаю все как есть.