# Что такое миграция в EntityFramework?

Tags: база-данных, .net, entity-framework

Начал изучать EF с подходом Code First и при изменении модели столкнулся с ошибкой, которую можно разрешить с помощью миграций. Никак мне могу понять что они из себя представляют. Получается, что если я произвожу доработку модели, то на каждое такое изменение мне нужно создавать миграцию? Но зачем их столько плодить и как их правильно удалять?

Comment: *миграция* это ничто иное как sql скрипт который вносит изменения в существующую бд(добавление таблиц, полей в таблицы, удаление полей и таблиц и.т.п.) чуть более подробно можно почитать например [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.12.php)

Comment: если под удалением миграции вы подразумеваете не хранить старые миграции, то тогда можно поступить как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646332/179270)

Comment: @Bald, спасибо. А как поступить, если мое приложение находится в разработке и нет нужды сохранять данные в базе при каждой сборке? Мне было бы проще чтобы бд создавалась заново каждый раз

Comment: для этого надо настроить инициализатор базы данных: [DropCreateDatabaseAlways](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.9.php)

Comment: _Мне было бы проще чтобы бд создавалась заново каждый раз_ - просто удаляйте БД. Клик правой кнопкой мыши - Delete. При отсутствии БД она будет создана EF.

Comment: _Но зачем их столько плодить_ - если необходимо сохранить в БД уже существующие данные.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не могу найти бд в структуре проекта. Где ее найти чтобы удалять?

Comment: Sql Server Object Explorer, например. Также можно воспользоваться Management Studio. Внимание: не _файл_ бд нужно удалять, а саму бд из СУБД!

Answer (score 4):

Миграции позволяют упростить развёртывание приложения, когда оно уже в работе. Предположим, вы добавили новое поле в таблицу при разработке, но в рабочей базе его нет. Если вы обновите приложение без обновления структуры базы, работать оно не сможет.

Миграция это средство поддержания структуры БД в актуальном состоянии.

После того, как вы добавили или удалили поле, добавили класс (и прописали его в `DbContext`), изменили параметры полей в entity configuration, вы должны создать новую миграцию с помощью команды `Add-Migration`, которую надо запустить из **Project Management Console**.

Entity Framework автоматически сгенерирует для вас код миграции, то есть вызовы, создающие поля или таблицы. Иногда вам нужно подкорректировать этот код, например, если речь идёт о переименовании поля. Обычно ручная коррекция требуется нечасто. Код класса-миграции выглядит так:

```cs
public partial class AddAmount : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<decimal>(
            name: "Amount",
            schema: "paymentSystem",
            table: "Payment",
            type: "money",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0m);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Amount",
            schema: "paymentSystem",
            table: "Payment");
    }
}
```

Как видим, есть два метода `Up` и `Down`, первый из которых позволяет изменить структуру базы *вверх*, а второй — *вниз*.

При старте приложения, EF будет проверять соответствие структуры БД в приложении и структуры БД в базе. Если они отличаются, EF достроит недостающую часть, вызывая методы `Up` у миграций, которые есть в приложении, но отсутствуют в базе.

В некоторых сложных случаях вам придётся писать код миграций самому. Речь идёт о случаях, когда структура базы кардинально меняется, и вам нужно сохранить старые данные. EF в этом случае не спасёт, но он упрощает очень много из простой работы.

Если вы работаете над проектом очень долго, количество миграций может стать очень большим. Их можно убрать из проекта, но делается это вручную, с пониманием, как устроены миграции.

**UPDATE**

Рекомендации, как правильно удалять миграции из [статьи](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate) Рика Страхла:

1. Удалить таблицу `_MigrationHistory` в базе данных. В EF Core таблица называется `__EFMigrationHistory`.
2. Удалить файлы миграций из проекта. Они имеют имена вида **20190403082834_AddAmount.cs**.
3. Выполнить команду `Add-Migration InitialCreate`.
4. Закомментировать код в методе `Up` созданной миграции.
5. Выполнить команду `Update-Database`.
6. Убрать комментарии в методе `Up`, то есть вернуть первоначальный код на место.

Comment: спасибо. Вы могли бы привести пример, когда нужно сохранять миграцию для каждого изменения модели? Т.е. для чего может понадобится сотня миграций при разработке?

Comment: @Mihail миграция отображает как изменялась структура бд, если вам это не надо вы можете схлопнуть миграции(или делать так периодически). этот как хранение истории разработки в системе контроля версий. кстати использование миграций позволяет *ходить* по истории изменений, т.е. вернуть состояние бд к более раннему состоянию

Comment: @Mihail Миграции *приходится* сохранять при каждом изменении модели, иначе приложение не сможет работать. Они копятся и время от времени их удаляют. Мы, по крайней мере, за три года разработки, удаляли миграции, кажется, три раза, когда их становилось за сорок.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, а как их правильно удалять? Если удалить .cs файлы, то это ведь не будет корректно?

Comment: @Mihail, процедура описана, например, Риком Страхлом. Добавил перевод в текст ответа.